# how can I see invisible or non-printing non-whitespace characters in WebStorm?

Tags: unicode, webstorm

Somehow I got an invisible non-whitespace character into a line in a bash script file. It was causing all sorts of issues when I pasted the line into another program. Whitespace is set to show (View -> Active Editor) but this character is still invisible. When I open that file in TextWrangler it's visible as an upside down ?:

`start.js ¿"./lib/da`

I suspect I inserted a unicode character with the Control key by accident (OSX). How can I spot a character like this while I'm editing scripts in Webstorm?

Comment: Please try **Zero Width Characters locator** plugin -- it may help here with detection of invisible characters. As far as I'm aware IDE itself does not have such functionality.

Comment: In any case: can you share such file (I mean actual file that can be downloaded and not just copy-paste from it; you can remove all other lines and only leave the one that has that issue)? I wander what those characters are (I have suspicion that it could be UTF-8 BOM signature that you may have copied somehow)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display hidden characters by default (ZERO WIDTH SPACE ie. &#8203)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868796/how-to-display-hidden-characters-by-default-zero-width-space-ie-8203)