# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in node.js

Tags: node.js, cloud9

I wrote the following code and ran it successfully on my local machine:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.send("OK");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
    console.log("listening on port " + process.env.PORT);
});
```

When I tried to run it on Cloud9 virtual machine, I encountered the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:441:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

I looked at these posts: [No visible cause for "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal), [How to display hidden characters in PhpStorm, especially line seperators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298042/how-to-display-hidden-characters-in-phpstorm-especially-line-seperators).

This error means that there is probably an invisible character in the code. I installed "Zero Width Characters locator" plugin in my WebStorm, copied the code from Cloud9 and got no sign for illegal character.

What can be the problem?

Comment: do you simply copy & paste your above code to your cloud9 instance? I just did that and it seems to run fine for me

Comment: Yes. I now did it again, I copied the code from here, pasted it in Cloud9 and still got the same error.

Comment: could you share your cloud9 instance with me? Not sure how to do that specifically, but my user name is paulsiii

Comment: I sent you an invitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain if this is the issue or not, but...

Your command `/home/ubuntu//.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/bin/node ./server/test.js` appears to be the issue. If you simply run `server/test.js` it seems to work fine

Comment: you're right. Now the code compiles. Now, how can I access it from a client computer?

Comment: I get the message:
"Your code is running at https://*****1986.c9users.io."

Now, I'm trying to access https://*****1986.c9users.io:3000 in the browser, and I don't get anything.

Comment: ok that is a new one for me. I don't use cloud9 hardly ever. That may be a new/different question. I'll keep looking though