# jQuery - File save error

Tags: jquery

I am getting a error when saving my php file that I have used jQuery in. I have located the exact script that gives me the error message, and also breaks the jQuery on the page. Can anyone tell what is wrong with this? I cant see why it would give me an encoding error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var left = 0;
    $('#breadcrumbs-list > li').each(function() {
        $(this).css('left', left + 'px');
        left += 100;
    });​
});​
```

Error: the document's current encoding can not correctly save all of the characters within the document. You may want to change to UTF-8 or an encoding that supports special characters in this document

Comment: what is relation between your post title and this code? you code seems well.

Comment: This script you posted is VALID and is used to displace your `li` elements at += 100 px each starting from 0px

Comment: Why do you use JS for this at all? USe CSS with proper relative positioning!

Comment: I am getting an error when I try to save the file(in dreamweaver) before uploading to the server to test.

Comment: @patrick Dreamweaver? Well there's your problem right there ;) Just playing. What is the error you're getting, and do you have jQuery referenced, perhaps the Google CDN version?

Comment: @ThiefMaster, the list is dynamically generated from a CMS. I can't control the output.

Comment: @Jonathan... I know, I am a designer what can i say... also I am sourcing jQuery via wordpress, it is using 1.4.1 from the google library

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two illegal invisible characters in your code.  From what I can tell, they're both just after the last two semicolons.

Position the cursor as far to the right of each semicolon as possible, and use backspace. You'll notice that one of the backspaces doesn't move the cursor. That's the illegal character being removed.

You can also observer this behavior without actually backspacing. Just move the cursor with the arrow keys, and again, you'll notice that when the invisible character is encountered, the cursor won't move for that one keypress.

---

The exact character is `"\u200B"` in both cases.

[Here's another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973698/whats-html-character-code-8203) that explains what that character is.

Comment: hmm, I can't seem to find it within my code. also, I am debugging with chrome, and it gives me 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?' after the last line of that script

Comment: @patrick: What do you mean by "find it"? Like I said, they're invisible. You successfully copied the characters into the question. That's how I was able to find them. You just need to follow the instructions in my answer to remove them. It's possible that there are more as well.

Comment: thanks, I just ended up re-writing the script and it solved the problem. I am wondering where this came from could it be from copy and pasting from jsfiddle? also: Thanks!

Comment: @patrick: Yes, that's exactly where it came from. I've encountered the same issue in the past with code from jsFiddle.