# Get checkbox with specific value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to get checkbox with specfic value and make it checked..

I make like this

```
$(":checkbox").filter({"value":5}).attr("checked","true");​
```

and here is the html

```
​<input type="checkbox" name="priv"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ value="1"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​/>
<input type="checkbox" name="priv" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="priv" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="priv" value="4"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="priv" value="5"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="priv" value="6"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="priv" value="7"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="priv" value="8"/>​
```

here's  a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wnUJ/) of the problem

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get the checkboxes with particular value. Also use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) as that is recommended way by [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LCU4C/2/)

```
$(":checkbox[value=4]").prop("checked","true");
```

or

```
$("input[type=checkbox][value=5]").prop("checked",true);
```

**Description:** Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value, [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

You can also do it Using attr() but prop is more appropriate for boolean properties.

```
$(":checkbox[value=4]").attr("checked","true");
```

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method, [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

**Edit**, asked in comments, "*How would look like the answer/find-expression with complex values, like value="Smith, David*"

You can enclose that kind of values like *Smith, David* on single quotes. You can even use character used by jQuery like #, ., $ etc, see updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LCU4C/433/).

```
$("input[type=checkbox][value='#Smith, David$']").attr("checked","true");
```

Comment: Stole me half an hour: The semicolon in your second code example is kind of evil. When you copy the whole line (`$("input[type=checkbox][value=5]").prop("checked",true);`) and paste it in your script, SublimeText + JSHint (in my case) will throw the error 'Unexpected'. The browser **stops executing** your code with the error 'Unexpected token ILLEGAL'. Deleting the semicolon and replacing it with a "fresh" one helped me (imagine my debbuging desperation...) I guess there is a hidden ascii-char or sth

Comment: Edit: sorry for double posting: `vim` showed me the little extra character:
`$("input[type=checkbox][value=5]").prop("checked",true);<200b>`

Comment: Sorry to know that the hidden character in the statement bothered you so much. I analyzed, traced and removed it. Thanks for pointing as it could save time of others.

Comment: I found character having code 8203, you can find more over here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973698/whats-html-character-code-8203

Comment: How would look like the answer/find-expression with complex values, like `value="Smith, David"`?

Answer (score 11):

```
$(":checkbox").filter(function() {
  return this.value == '5';
}).prop("checked","true");​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/59hHK/)

If you want to use it for different values then make it generic like following:

```
function checkWithValue(val) {
    $(":checkbox").filter(function() {
        return this.value == val;
    }).prop("checked", "true");
}


checkWithValue(5);​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/59hHK/3/)**

Answer (score 4):

```
$("input:checkbox[value='5']").attr("checked","true")
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a dynamic values that needed to be looped over. This is what worked for me:

```
for (var i = 0, len = value.length; i < len; i++) {
  $("#form-name").find("input[type=checkbox][name='fName']").filter(function () {
    return this.value == values[i];
  }).prop("checked", true);
}
```

Hope that helps someone out.

Answer (score 1):

It works also with square practise

```
 $(":checkbox").filter(["value":5]).prop("checked","true");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Sometimes we want to get checkbox dynamically for a specific value.**

```
$(document).on('click','.at-filter a', function(){
    var aaa = $(this).parent().find("em").html();
    $("input[type=checkbox][value='"+aaa+"']").prop('checked',false)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":checkbox[value=5]").attr("checked",true);​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#catalogTBL").find("input[type=checkbox][value='snet']").prop("checked", true);
```

This was the only way I could get this to work.  Looking for a checkbox in a table.