# Set checkbox with specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm looking for a way in jQuery console to checkbox selected values in Chrome (ie. 416800-000). I have found ways to do it but my HTML situation is a bit different. Going off the name parameter isn't doable for me.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="value[1].value" value="416800-000" class="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="value[1].enabled" value="on">
```

The above value when type is hidden can by dynamic.

Here is a demo of my problem

https://jsfiddle.net/68ujpfrw/1/

Similar to this case [Get checkbox with specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930048/get-checkbox-with-specific-value/34759956#34759956)

**Edit:** Also, is it possible to do find a text (ie. Admin) then do the checkbox?

```html
<input type="hidden" name="value[1].value" value="416800-000" class="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="value[1].enabled" value="on">

    "Admin"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since the actual/visible checkbox is after the hidden one then you can simply use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and then set the attribute value.

```
$("input[value='416800-000']").next().prop("checked", true);​
```

Updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3w7kk60x/)

```js
$("input[value='416800-000']").next().prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="value[1].value" value="416800-000" class="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="value[1].enabled" value="on">
```

**EDIT:** I'd suggest to add the "Admin" text in a `span` tag to help select the element and then use [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to select the checkbox

```
$("span:contains('Admin')").prev().prop('checked', true);
```

Updated the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3w7kk60x/2/) for this case.

```js
$("span:contains('Super User')").prev().prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="value[1].value" value="416800-000" class="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="value[1].enabled" value="on">
<span>Admin</span>
<input type="hidden" name="value[1].value" value="416900-000" class="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="value[1].enabled" value="on">
<span>User</span>
<input type="hidden" name="value[1].value" value="417000-000" class="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="value[1].enabled" value="on">
<span>Super User</span>
```

Comment: Thanks - this did it for me! =D

Comment: Is there is a way to find a text for example "Admin" after input type checkbox - is it possible to do the same thing ( added to main post)

Comment: @DavidL.Lee - Check the edit to my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: - I don't have access to modify the HTML - can we select the element still without the span tag

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery:

```
$('#your-checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```