# checkbox checked issue in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set checkbox `checked` on document load, if check box `value="1"`, and unchecked if `value="0"`.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
```

**Jquery:** which is wrong, tried many things

```
$(document).ready ('input[type="checkbox"]', function(event) {
  if ($(this).val==1) {
    $(this).is(":checked")
  }
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattii/bfsq192c/20/)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get checkbox with specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930048/get-checkbox-with-specific-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[***`.ready()`***](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) accepts a function as the single parameter which is executed after the DOM is ready.

You do not need any condition to check the value manually. You can simply use *attribute* selector:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][value=1]').attr('checked', true);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox][value=1]').attr('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Comment: @Fayakon, logically the solution should work. It is really hard to tell the issue without seeing the example code with json:)

Comment: just curious how we pass any variable as value? $('input[type=checkbox][variable=1]').attr('checked', true);

Comment: @Fayakon, if `v` is the value then you can write `$('input[type=checkbox][value='+v+']').attr('checked', true);`

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors. First this line `ready ('input[type="checkbox"]', function(event) {` .`ready` receives a callback function and your code is wrong there. Secondly in `if ($(this).val==1) {` `val` is a method. So that will require `braces`. You can nly use attribute selector and marked it as checked.Also `$(this).is(":checked")` return a boolean value but it never checks a checkbox

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[type="checkbox"][value="1"]').prop('checked', true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Comment: data is loading in json format, your code works fine with hardcore value, but when json is changing value to 0/1 checkbox is not changing.

Comment: @Fayakon you never told before that it is loading from json. In that case you need to show more code which loads json

Comment: Thanks figured it out.