# Code working fine online but fails on local file

Tags: jquery

please look this code : [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/Orina/bQZTq/)

this code work in jsfiddle.net but not work on local
js code in local ,
this code show and hide more less text

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
      var maxheight=118;
      var showText = "More";
      var hideText = "Less";

      $('.textContainer_Truncate').each(function () {
        var text = $(this);
        if (text.height() > maxheight){
            text.css({ 'overflow': 'hidden','height': maxheight + 'px' });

            var link = $('<a href="#">' + showText + '</a>');
            var linkDiv = $('<div></div>');
            linkDiv.append(link);
            $(this).after(linkDiv);

            link.click(function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              if (text.height() > maxheight) {
                  $(this).html(showText);
                  text.css('height', maxheight + 'px');
              } else {
                  $(this).html(hideText);
                  text.css('height', 'auto');
              }
            });
        }       
      });
   });​
</script>
```

htm code :

```
<div class="textContainer_Truncate">
      <p>content<br>
        hello<br>
        hello<br>
        hello<br>
          hello<br>
          hello<br>
          hello<br>
          hello<br>
          hello<br>
          hello<br>
          hello<br>
          hello<br>
          hello<br>
          hello<br>
          hello<br>
          hello<br>
          hello<br>
        </p>
    </div>
```

content of folder :
index.htm and jquery-1.8.2.min.js
how to use this code on local ?

Comment: Please define 'not work' (as this can mean a lot of things - from slight hiccups in JS behaviour to blowing up the whole computer; hopefully, it's not the latter) and show the complete source of that HTML file (index.htm that is).

Comment: is "jquery-1.8.2.min.js" the correct include path?

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zbjhX/ . 
It is created by me based on your script and html. Its working fine. Plz check your script references in your local code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to replicate what you have done and found that it's working fine with no error.

consider to download this solution (a folder contains an index.html page along side with jquery 1.8.2.js file).
maybe you have made something extra
[Test Project](http://www.mediafire.com/?8un6v06qzvr09rn)

Update: I've noticed something when copying your code, there is an extra questionmark in your code, look at the following picture

[image]

Comment: Good catch, I also saw that and confirmed this to be [zero width space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973698/whats-html-character-code-8203)