# Why div resize will not fit browser window when reducing vertical size?

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize

Consider the following simple html page:

```
<doctype>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is my page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body style="padding:0px;margin:0px">
        <div id="root" style="background-color:#dddddd;width:100px;height:100px;position:relative">
            <div id="graph" style="background-color:#00ff00;width:200px;height:200px;position:absolute;bottom:0px">
                This is the DW box
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).resize(function(){
                $('#root').width($(window).width());
                $('#root').height($(window).height());
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see by using `jQuery` I resize div `root` in order to fit the window. If you try the code (at least on Chrome, my version is Chrome 23) what happens is that `root` will constantly fit the browser window horizontally. Vertically fitting is also performed correctly but only when incrementing browser's window height.

If you try to expand your browser window vertically, no problem. But, after expanding, if you try to reduce the vertical seize of your browser window, `root` will not fit it!

### Demo

You can see my window here.

[image]

Here I expand, nothing wrong, the grey box (root) expands.

[image]

Unfortunately the snapshot tool does not show the scrollbar but it is evident that when reducing the vertical size, the grey box does not fit...

[image]

Why is this? How to fix this? Thankyou

#### PS

You see a div named `graph`. That div is supposed to stay in the lower part of the browser window.

Comment: Why not use 100% width and height in CSS?

Comment: I thought that not all browser would behave in the same way.. Some of them have different behaviors when applying 100% height. Honestly this is something I learnt from an article some years ago... In Chrome it is ok, 100% height works, but what about the other browsers?

Comment: Well years ago is most likely totally out of date for something like this. I've never really experienced any problems due to 100% height and width of elements in modern browsers. It's a pretty fundamental part of presentation and they all seem to have it down. IE might differ, but that's to be expected no matter what you do.

Comment: When I look at it with the Chrome Code Inspector I see that somewhere about your closing script tag there is a "zero width space", which affects in a break right after "root". For more information: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973698/whats-html-character-code-8203)

Comment: If you full screen your browser, the vertical fits perfect.

Answer (score 2):

The point here is that jQuery(window).height() == document.documentElement.clientHeight (as for jQuery 1.8+), which behaves differently in different browsers.

$(document).height() returns the highest between scrollHeight, offsetHeight and clientHeight - yet a very different result between browsers.

So it's actually ***less*** cross-browser than using CSS. That's what you should do:

```
html,body { height:100%; }
#root { min-height:100%; position:relative; }
#graph { position:absolute; bottom:0; }
```

Comment: @Mr_Green what i'm saying is that javascript-recovered height isn't "more compatible" than pure css. That's the jQuery 1.6 function:

`var docElemProp = elem.document.documentElement[ "client" + name ];
   return elem.document.compatMode === "CSS1Compat" && docElemProp ||
    elem.document.body[ "client" + name ] || docElemProp;`

and thats the new one: `return elem.document.documentElement[ "client" + name ];`

Comment: I misunderstood by seeing `1.8+` :)

Comment: :) i meant "jQuery(window).height() == document.documentElement.clientHeight in jQuery 1.8+" @Mr_Green , because before 1.8 `$(window).height()` returned a different equation, better in my opinion.

Comment: OK, my question now is... is it possible to retrieve the correct window height using javascript in order to resize a div? I really cannot believe that there is no way to retrieve height in a browser... it sounds so impossible to me... btw thanks for your post, really useful!

Comment: i did some testing @Andry , with window.innerHeight you get the "right" height in any browser EXCEPT Webkit based (Chrome, Safari, Android etc) and IE<9 ... So no, there's no direct way in javascript. That's what i came out with, but it involves user agent sniffing (booo) : `var height = (RegExp(" AppleWebKit/").test(navigator.userAgent)) ? document.documentElement.clientHeight :
 ( window.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight );`

Comment: P.S. it fails anyway on IE<9, because `document.body.clientHeight` is shorter then the user's window IF the body element is shorter than full height (ie: no vertical scrollbars). Trust me, you need css @Andry ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To `make it cross browser` for this `you have to use css` for `html and body` too.

in my fiddle i made a change in the css:

```
html,body{height:100%;}
```

then the little change in the jquery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#root').width('100%'); // <---100% width
    $('#root').height('100%'); //<---100% height
});
```

and this way you can't get the glitch in expanding or shrinking the window.

checkout the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D6YUr/2/

Comment: Jai thanks but I am not looking for a trick... The point is that inside that div I need to put some stuff, and in particular there is a div located in the bottom which must always be in the lower part of the browser window... See my edit please and apply your change... look at what happens to div 'graph'.

Comment: thats weired! You can checkout the updated answer and the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is possible using only CSS i.e.  `height: 100%`

Check here for [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/height) of height css property.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ogimut/9/)**

Comment: Mr_Green sorry it does not work... As you reduce the height, you see vertical scroll appear... the div size will not fit... Sorry but thanks a lot for your concern :(

Comment: @Andry Ya I understand it now.. sorry I misunderstood your explanation.. I will try it :)

Comment: I had a feeling :( btw thanks for the browser compatibility page... I wanted good data but all only found blogs... not really reliable... I did not know that mozilla foundation had published compatibility info for CSS specifications... thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I already wrote in the comments I just see one problem. The zero width space (`&#8203;`). Thats a invisible Unicode character, which is used to mark where a word can be separated (at the end of the line). How it get in your code I really dont know. So I just retyped your code (The only solution I know to remove it)
Here is the result:

```
<doctype>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is my page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body style="padding:0px;margin:0px">
        <div id="root" style="background-color:#dddddd;width:100px;height:100px;position:relative">
            <div id="graph" style="background-color:#00ff00;width:50px;height:20px;position:absolute;bottom:0px">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).resize(function(){
                $('#root').width($(window).width());
                $('#root').height($(window).height());
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It looks exactly the same but the zero width space is removed.

Comment: Thankyou for your concern. I applied your code just cut and pasted it... The point is that nothing changes... I mean I have the same problem with div resize not fitting vertical size. Does your code in your browser work? I mean, this white space character affects vertical resize?

Comment: Yes in my browser the code does perfectly work. What browser do you use? And could you maybe upload a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: I use Chrome 23 on MacOS. OK, gonna publish a screenshot, did not think about this sorry...