# Google file picker example breaks when you choose different view e.g. google.picker.ViewId.DOCS

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, cut-and-paste

I've gotten the  [google file picker example](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) to work. The example uses the photos view and that works fine. But when I change the view to e.g. google.picker.ViewId.DOCS. Iget a javascript error;

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I'm using the correct scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) according to the documentation. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is I was cut-and-pasting the view name from the [developers guide](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/). Unfortunately, the view names in the guide all contained a hidden character, the [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973698/whats-html-character-code-8203). The character didn't appear in my editor, but was screwing up the javascript interpreter. I only spotted it in the chrome debugger tools as a red dot in my code