# How delete zero-width space in String javascript and my comparacion return true

Tags: javascript, jquery, zero-width-space

I have a javascript string containing 3 zero-width space.

https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/pe1jup8a/

4 returns when var.length use.

[image]

My question is how can I delete the zero-width space to be able to compare

```
"." === "."
```

and return true.

in [JavaScript remove ZERO WIDTH SPACE (unicode 8203) from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205193/javascript-remove-zero-width-space-unicode-8203-from-string)

I found a solution, but is not valid for this, I try

```
 var a =".";
 var b = a.replace(/\u200B/g,'');
 var c = a.replace(/\u200B/g,'');
 console.log(a.length);
 console.log(b);
 console.log(c.length);
```

but always returns 4 characters.

https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/kxk2raaL/

Comment: .trim() doesn't seem to handle it, so you can always fake up your own and explicitly add zero-width spaces to the "to-be-removed" chars list, as per the prototype shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim