# Jquery Invisible string in input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys please help me with this.

i have some issue regarding some email validation that doesn't match my regex.
What's my issues all about was i think are \n or \r but when i try

```
var count = $("input#email_address").val().length;
```

Got the result of 25 when copy from excel to my text box VS Manual input with the same text and the result is 24 characters.

```
var str = $("input#email_address").val().replace(/\r?\n/g, "");
```

i tried this and trim() and match to find \r \n or whitespaces but return null.

Comment: Are you trying to replace all, or just one time?

Comment: did i missed something here? im new to jquery and javascript.

Comment: @applecrusher just one time.

Comment: Try this, excel adds more tabs
var str = $("input#email_address").val().replace(/[\r\n\t]/g, "");

Comment: Take a look at the answers here. It might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: @MoustafaS i tried it but still counts as 25 character instead of 24 :(

Comment: Did you try just `.val().trim()` ?

Comment: @adeneo yeah i tried that after i get the value from input text.

Comment: @applecrusher thanks dude.. :) i'll check that out

Comment: Related link, but probably not helpful :)  https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: This is the scariest string i found in my input text value after using escape(str) command in js.

it outputs "%u200Btest@test.com" holy god where did it came from? it should be "test@test.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay in case you encounter this. Here's the solution.

I checked the value of my input text by calling escape(str), and i got the result
**"%u200Btest@test.com"** it should be **"test@test.com"** they called this zero width space(correct me if i'm wrong".

and here's the fix.

```
str = str.replace(/\u200B/g,'');
```

[JavaScript remove ZERO WIDTH SPACE (unicode 8203) from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205193/javascript-remove-zero-width-space-unicode-8203-from-string)

Answer (score 1):

First remove all unreadable characters, just in case:

```
var str = $("input#email_address").val().replace(/[\x00-\x1f]+/g, "");
```

Then, you should also check if some special characters in the string are multibyte. In that case, you need a more elaborated approach, see:

[String length in bytes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript)