# Remove the first unicode character in a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, unicode

I have a paragraph that is injected with an annoying &#8203 unicode character at the beginning of paragraph tags. (it's because of a Microsoft SharePoint CMS bug)

Using javascript, how would I write an if statement that searches if it exists and removes it? It is always the first character in the paragraph.

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205193/javascript-remove-zero-width-space-unicode-8203-from-string

Answer (score 0):

The following removes all instances of that character (U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE) from a string:

```
s = s.replace(/\u200B/g, "");
```

Keep in mind that 8203<sub>10</sub> = 200B<sub>16</sub>.

Comment: curious, what does the sub 10 and sub 16 mean?

Comment: Base 10 (decimal) and 16 (hexadecimal)