# Unable to remove %e2%80%8b Unicode from string

Tags: php, string, unicode, twig

I'm unable to remove a Unicode character from a string. In the following twig template.

```
  {% include 'components/accordion.twig' with {
      this: {
        id: program.slug,
        active: (loop.index == 1) ? true : false,
        header: header,
        body: body,
        cta: {
          href: program.get_permalink,
          text: __('Learn More', 'accessnyc-locations')
        }
      }
    } only %}
  {% endfor %}
```

The `programs.slug` returns a string with the Unicode %e2%80%8b

```
"aria-c-senior-citizens-rent-increase-exemption-%e2%80%8bscrie"
```

From the following [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string) it seems that the `%e2%80%8b` is somehow added to the string. When I try to replace it from the string the output string still the same. The correct output should be

```
"aria-c-senior-citizens-rent-increase-exemption-scrie"
```

I tried using `replace(/\u200B/g,'');` as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205193/javascript-remove-zero-width-space-unicode-8203-from-string), without success. How can I go about removing Unicode characters from a string?

here is what I tried:

```
program.dataset.id  = program.id.replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', 'cookie');
"aria-c-senior-citizens-rent-increase-exemption-%e2%80%8bscrie"
program.dataset.id  = program.id.replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '');
"aria-c-senior-citizens-rent-increase-exemption-%e2%80%8bscrie"
   program.dataset.id  = program.id.replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', 'cookie');
    "aria-c-senior-citizens-rent-increase-exemption-%e2%80%8bscrie"
```

i also tried

```
   {% autoescape %}
    {% include 'components/accordion.twig' with {
      this: {
        id: {{ programs.slug|raw }},
        active: (loop.index == 1) ? true : false,
        header: header,
        body: body,
        cta: {
          href: program.get_permalink,
          text: __('Learn More', 'accessnyc-locations')
        }
      }
    } only %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endautoescape %}
```

How can I go about removing these from the string?

Comment: Because this is a slug, you might also probably want to remove any non-alphanumeric so `/[^\da-z]/i` might work for you.

Comment: Edit it in the DB.

Comment: @Kerkouch it didn't work: ```string.id.replace(/[^\da-z]/i,'');
"ariac-senior-citizens-rent-increase-exemption-%e2%80%8bscrie"```

Comment: What about `/(%[\da-z]{2})/i`?

Comment: @Kerkouch no luck :(