# How to get rid of empty white space at the bottom

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

I have a [blogger website](http://www.ilovetrolls.org/).I don't have any footer.

There exists a 20px heighted white space at the extreme bottom. I want to remove it.

Here is what i have tried so far.

1.) Since the height of the empty space is 20px, I searched through the entire code for `20px` value

2.)I used Chrome's `inspect element`, nothing could be traced.

3.)Hunted for `<br>` tags

4) Added this code

```
html, body { height: 100% !important; }
```

5). Tried this as well

```
 body { margin: 0 !important;}
```

6.) And this too

```
 #body (margin-bottom: 0px !important;}
```

I am totally clueless as I have already explored the entire web for troubleshooting.Any tips?

Comment: Please paste _all_ relevant parts of your code here. Potential answerers shouldn't have to go to your live website in order to answer your question, it also indicates that the historical value of this question to future visitors of the site will be diminished once your live page changes. In your case, your question may benefit from a picture of the problem.

Comment: This seems very specific to your site: Right before your Google Analytics `<script>`, you have `&#8203;`. Deleting this makes the spacing at the bottom go away. [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973698/whats-html-character-code-8203) (that question's accepted answer has what that character code is, and a possible cause of its inclusion).

Comment: @esqew shall take care of it :)

Comment: @ajp15243 Thanks a lot.How can i give u credit...thanks for the link.....could have never traced it

Comment: @Michel I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you inspect your page's source code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> on some OSes, but right-click and `View Source` or `View page source` or equivalent should show it), you'll see the following preceding your Google Analytics `<script>`:

```
</script>
                        &#8203; 

<script type='text/javascript'>
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

The culprit is the `&#8203;` HTML entity, which according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973713/1883647) is the [Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). The answer notes that it is likely the character was accidentally entered due to an alternate language input, like an Arabic key mapping. This is adding a line of space to your site because web browsers aren't going to treat it like the normal ASCII space character (i.e. usually ignore it), and will instead explicitly print the whitespace character. This causes the browser to lay out a line of space for it.

Removing this from your source code should fix the problem.  It may not show up in your IDE/text editor, in which case you're better off erasing all of the space between those script tags and re-adding the desired spacing manually.