# Use of undefined constant ​ - assumed '​' in php

Tags: php

```
    <?php
         $f=$_POST['rdate'];
          echo $f."</br>";
           $from=$f.'-01 00:00:00';
           $dayyy=explode("-",$f);
           //print_r($dayyy);
           $year=$dayyy[0];
           echo $year."</br>";
           $mm=$dayyy[1];   
            echo $mm."</br>";
        $mons = array("01" => "Janauary", "02" => "February", "03"=>"March", "04"=>"April", "05"=>"May", "06"=>"June", "07"=>"July", "08"=>"August", "09"=>"September", "10"=>"October", "11"=>"November", "12"=>"December");
        print_r($mons);
        /*foreach($mons as $mm)
        {
          echo $mm; 
        }*/
        $month_name = $mons[$mm];
        echo "</br>".$month_name;
      $days=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mm, $year);
        $dayss= $days-1;
        echo $dayss."</br>";
        $dayys=' + '.$dayss.' days' ;
        $var=$from.$dayys;
        //echo $var."</br>";
        echo "Last".date('Y-m-d 23:59:59',strtotime($var));​

        ?>
```

i'm getting  Use of undefined constant ​ - assumed error in the above code.
I guess i got this issue due to non breaking spce but don't know where i left that?
Kindly help!!

---

Comment: What line gives the error?

Comment: try to change this `$days=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mm, $year);` to `$days=cal_days_in_month(0, $mm, $year);`

Comment: I have simply copied your code and run it there is no error.tell where you are getting the error.

Comment: The error is pretty common. It means that you have a typo, or are using a constant that isn't defined. PHP defaults to interpreting that piece of quote as though it were quoted (ie a string literal). To fix: make sure the `CAL_GREGORIAN` constant exists (`var_dump(defined('CAL_GREGORIAN'));`), check if you didn't omit a `$` sign somewhere, and ensure you have no typo's in any functions you call. Also check the file encoding, the code is best saved as UTF-8

Comment: it shows in this line $to = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59',strtotime($from.$dayys));

Comment: var_dump(defined('CAL_GREGORIAN')); it shows bool(true)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some kind of weird character on your

```
echo "Last".date('Y-m-d 23:59:59',strtotime($var));
```

line
notepad++ couldn't see it but when I tried to arrow throw it, it went through twice.

Anyways, remove the line and copy and paste this

```
echo "Last".date('Y-m-d 23:59:59',strtotime($var));
```

Comment: i encoded it in ANSI and saw it 
    echo "Last".date('Y-m-d 23:59:59',strtotime($var));â€‹

Comment: i didn't get like that

Comment: WOW!! i got rectified that issue....but i have a question,both lines are same but how i can got the answer with out that issue

Comment: whatever encoding your text editor was using just couldn't read that character. All i did was comment lines out starting from the bottom until it worked, then i could start narrowing down possibilities. And then i rewrote the line by hand, and it worked. So i figured there was an encoding issue. In notepad++ you can go to 'Encoding' -> Convert to ____ to check out different character sets

Comment: That "weird" character, is a Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B) - See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/2973698/

Comment: Good to know thanks! Don't know my character encodings well enough clearly!

Comment: You have told about the notepad++, in that "convert to ________", fill that dash ji....because there is lot of options in encoding option..by selecting which option i can remove  that space

Answer (score 0):

check the constant you are using is defined or not ..
if not define it

the code will be

```
<?php 

  if (!defined('CAL_GREGORIAN')) 
    define('CAL_GREGORIAN', 0); 

   $f=$_POST['rdate'];
          echo $f."</br>";
           $from=$f.'-01 00:00:00';
           $dayyy=explode("-",$f);
           //print_r($dayyy);
           $year=$dayyy[0];
           echo $year."</br>";
           $mm=$dayyy[1];   
            echo $mm."</br>";
        $mons = array("01" => "Janauary", "02" => "February", "03"=>"March", "04"=>"April", "05"=>"May", "06"=>"June", "07"=>"July", "08"=>"August", "09"=>"September", "10"=>"October", "11"=>"November", "12"=>"December");
        print_r($mons);
        /*foreach($mons as $mm)
        {
          echo $mm; 
        }*/
        $month_name = $mons[$mm];
        echo "</br>".$month_name;
      $days=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mm, $year);
        $dayss= $days-1;
        echo $dayss."</br>";
        $dayys=' + '.$dayss.' days' ;
        $var=$from.$dayys;
        //echo $var."</br>";
        echo "Last".date('Y-m-d 23:59:59',strtotime($var));
```

Comment: Sidenote: Your answer would not have worked, because it too contains the OP's  Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B) as stated in [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286083/use-of-undefined-constant-assumed-in-php#comment39406746_25286250).