# PHP - PDO Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

There are a lot of questions about this, but still I can't find a question which answers my question.

I got some code (obviously), which does a query to the database, and for some reason it is returning an error.

```
// ^ somewhere in the top session_start();
require("rw_conx.php");
try {
    // Get answers from database 
    $db = new PDO ("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $pass);
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT antwoorden, commentaar
                        FROM antwoorden
                        WHERE vragenlijst = :vragenlijst
                        AND meting = :meting
                        AND behandeltraject = :behandeltraject
                        AND onderzoeksNR = :onderzoeksnummer");
    $vragenlijst = "1";
    $meting = "1";
    $onderzoeksNR = trim(preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_SESSION["onderzoeksnummer"]));
    $behandeltraject = trim(preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_SESSION["behandeltraject"]));        
    $stmt->execute(array('vragenlijst'=>$vragenlijst,'meting'=>$meting,'behandeltraject'=>$behandeltraject,'onderzoeksnummer'=>$onderzoeksNR));
    // Render all questions (check if 5's should be hidden), input disabled, no answer categories.          
    $num_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT);

    // What this does is create a string like: 1=2,2=4,3=5|||COMMENTS|||1=blabla,2=blabla
    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        echo $row[0];
        echo "|||COMMENTS|||";
        echo $row[1];
    } else {
        echo "no data";
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that. (1)";
    file_put_contents('../debug.log', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
    exit();
}   

$stmt->execute(array('vragenlijst'=>$vragenlijst,'meting'=>$meting,'behandeltraject'=>$behandeltraject,'onderzoeksnummer'=>$onderzoeksNR));
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Just to make this clear, I will explain.

**1. I mentioned in my question above, that the sessions were no problem.**

What I meant by this was the fact, that the error that occured (SQLSTATE[HY093]) was not thrown because the sessions were empty.

**2. The problem still occurs.**

Even though the session_start() fixed the query (It now returns the row it should), I am still getting the same error, which is (of course) not supposed to happen.

I hope this clears things up a bit, because everybody is getting mad at me. I did indeed mention the sessions were no problem, and they **are no** problem for the error that occurs. For some reason the catch function still gives me an error, even though the query succesfully runs.

So, if there are still people who would like to help me out, I would really appreciate it.

**--- END EDIT ---**

Does anyone see the (probably obvious) flaw?

Comment: Check your column names in your table and make sure the types are correct.

Comment: As a test, can you try using `?` instead of `:name` for your parameters in the query, and use `array($vragenlijst, $meting, ...)` in the `execute` call?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol When I do as you say, it still gives me the same error ... but why?

Comment: @Fred-ii- the column names are correct, and what do you mean with the types?

Comment: Hmm, that is quite strange, then. I must admit that at this point I am stumped.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol so am I, when I run this query in DirectAdmin (so without the placeholders but just with the values `1` it returns a row...

Comment: Maybe if the column type is a VARCHAR and should be an `int`, it might make a difference. Also check if your column(s) does not contain a space or other hidden character. I've seen that happen before.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the columns are all ENUM('1','2'), spaces: none.

Comment: Could you export your SQL and paste it in the question?

Comment: Are all your column's data set to `1` though? Your query might be failing because of the `AND` for all of them. Can you try an `OR` instead? See what that says. At this point, I too am stumped.

Comment: Oh... wait a minute. You mention sessions. Did you start the session? Is `session_start();` included?  You mention in a comment below something about `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, I don't need `OR` because all of them need to be true. If that were true what you say, it wouldn't throw this error.

Comment: Did you see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689049/php-pdo-invalid-parameter-number#comment43792155_27689049) just above, about sessions?

Comment: Your code is correct, you should show us the original code with session

Comment: @Fred-ii- LOL turns out you're right, because I was sending a request to a page, instead of including it... You're da MAN! I thought I was including the page. Thank you so much :P

Comment: Ahhhh great! So, shall I make it an answer after all this? lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- You can if you like, you earned it :)

Comment: I have undeleted my original answer and made an edit to it. Glad we solved it, *cheers* - Reload it to see it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol In case you may not have seen it, the mystery has been solved ;-)

Comment: How is it possible that your code doesn't work with the hard-coded values?

Comment: @JiFus It seems like there's some sour grapes being thrown around here. I suggest you make an **edit** under your original question and post your actual code with what you're now using including `session_start();` etc. (and not your hard-code values), in order to clear this matter up 100% and not 99%. Having people sore about something isn't right and there's no reason to have any bad blood flowing here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You miss the point completely. It's not about who is wrong or wright. I just waste some time while I was willing to help the OP. After I saw the solution the whole question wasn't even valid and seems untested(hard-coded values should work). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @GuyT This whole thing is a genuine fiasco if you ask me. I don't even know which way to throw myself at this point. It's a he-said he-says. Had I known before gotten all this flack about it, I'd of never put in an answer. I asked the OP questions and during that process, the solution was found. The OP accepted my answer, so that's their business, not mine. Why I'm being dragged into all this, heck if I know. I didn't "start" this, it's not my problem and shouldn't be dragged in the mud for it. Far as I'm concerned, this matter is closed.

Comment: I think it is fair to also notify @Fred-ii- . Your edit 2 seems impossible to me. After you have added `session_start()` you got the expected result. The only thing that has changed by adding the `session_start()` is that your variables are set.

Comment: @Fred-ii- See my edit 2 please

Comment: @GuyT I know it seems impossible. I'll now paste in my real code.

Comment: Could you execute following command before the execute: `print_r(array('vragenlijst'=>$vragenlijst,'meting'=>$meting,'behandeltraject'=>$behandeltraject,'onderzoeksnummer'=>$onderzoeksNR));` and post the results?

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ')'` On the line with the `print_r` code...

Comment: Ahaaaa.. This could clear some things up. When I paste that code in: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ . You will see that the variable `$behandeltraject` is malformed after you run the code. A space will solve this issue. Probably an encoding error or something? When you look at the online compiler I have also noticed that all variables are blue, except the `$behandeltraject` one. **I have found it** You have a zero width space in your file(&#8203;)!

Comment: That's why the input parameters doesn't match(`$behandeltraject is not defined)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to a zero width space(`&#8203;` in unicode). This might be automatically added in the editor that you are using. jQuery will also insert zero width space characters as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973698/whats-html-character-code-8203).

### But why is it giving me the `SQLSTATE[HY093]` error?

This is because `$behandeltraject` is not defined(there is a zero width space in front of it) so the parameters will not match.

Comment: Way to go Guy. I have seen that before (unicode), but inside jQuery scripts that would break the OP's code, but never like this. I have modified my answer slightly.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, it's a strange issue. I guess the OP copied the code from somewhere else(probably a Dutch PHP lesson). I am glad we have solved it together(session + zero width space).

Comment: Indeed strange Guy. First time I got wind of a unicode character in OP's code some time back, pasted the whole thing in strangely enough (Notepad, then MS Frontpage). Frontpage displayed the hidden character as `&#8203;` where I started Googling it, having found what it was. There are other hidden characters that find their way into code, as to how they get there is sometimes a mystery; type of editor used or done online(?). I now use a proper IDE, but those that I've mention still serve me well (to a certain extent). *Cheers* and glad this matter was resolved; *finally*.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that the mystery has been solved *by GuyT <=(edit)*, am posting the following as per [a comment I left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689049/php-pdo-invalid-parameter-number#comment43792155_27689049) under OP's question:

You mention sessions. Did you start the session?

Is `session_start();` included?

You mentioned in a comment in another answer about `var_dump($_SESSION);`

`session_start();` is required to be inside all files using sessions.

---

Original answer, added one above:

You forgot the `$` sign for `onderzoeksNR` in

```
'onderzoeksnummer'=> onderzoeksNR
                    ^ right there
```

in regards to

```
$onderzoeksNR = "1";
```

change it to

```
'onderzoeksnummer'=>$onderzoeksNR
```

Comment: Good job, I was sure it had to be something obvious, but this? Cheers!

Comment: @JiFus Yeah, sometimes it's those little wee-things that makes it harder to figure out why something fails. I'm so glad that we were able to solve it :) *Cheers* and you're very much welcome.

Comment: Exactly what my guess was, first but OP said "noh I checked, it is correct, session not problem"

Comment: @DanFromGermany The `// Normally this are sessions...` in OP's code had me raise a brow from the start and I should have questioned it originally. This one was a tricky one.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Btw, is that your DV? If it is then it's uncalled for, don't be sore, you've no reason to attack me. Your answer wasn't the solution. I earned mine and asked the right questions.

Comment: I did answer this, 42 minutes ago "... one of the values is an array or null" ... without a session beeing started, the values are nulls...

Comment: @DanFromGermany You never made the mention about if the session was started.  Go over your own answer again. You included about doing it a different way, which doesn't matter. Either methods work. So, don't be sore about it, you've no reason to be. I could have easily DV'd yours, but I didn't. I had "no reason" to really. I'm not like that. I'll post a comment about it when I do. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- However guys, the code still throws an error, but It returns the row succesfully

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, that either the error is coming from a different statement, or one of the values is an array or null in your code using the session variables

```
// Normally this are sessions, I checked them, and they contain a value.
```

You should be using the `bindParam` member,

```
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

...because

1. it doesn't throw strange errors
2. using `execute()`, all params are converted to `string`.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: at your link (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) it says the following:

"you must either: call PDOStatement::bindParam() to bind PHP variables..." OR "pass an array of input-only parameter values" So why then does the array part not work?

Comment: I think the error is somewhere else. For me, `execute(array())`-style works. I guess your original code is different from the one above.

Comment: OP should just accept yours then, if it'll make you feel any better. Btw, both methods work in PDO, so you're partly wrong.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are correct that Dan is partly wrong, but his first thoughts were right. In my opinion this is a bad question. Certainly after the OP wrote *Normally this are sessions, I checked them, and they contain a value.* and at the end the values were empty.