# Regarding shift + enter with ckeditor inserting invisible character

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CK editor 4.4.6.

It seem on the first instance of pressing shift + enter, the editor inserts an invisible character. Upon submission, the character saves as a question mark. I can't see the character in the form submission when viewing the debug in the browser or the source code in the WYSIWYG editor itself. I do however notice when I press the right arrow that the cursor pauses at this character even though I can't see it. The page is being served in UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

This character is zero-width-space and is used by CKEditor to workaround Safari's and Blink's problems with placing selection inside empty inline tags or around them or in couple of other positions.

However, this character should never end up in data. It's used only internally and it is removed when getting data from editor. So, if you can find it in your database it means that you either get data from editor incorrectly, or you encounter some bug in the mechanism I described. In the latter is true please report a bug on http://dev.ckeditor.com, but please also describe how you reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the editor is inserting character 8203.

[What's HTML character code 8203?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973698/whats-html-character-code-8203)

I don't want to mess with the editor script at the moment so I'm just stripping out that character in the future on form/ajax post.