# Fastest (calculating) way to filter out a a portion of data from a big list of API data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that pulls data from an online JSON api. The data can be stored in variable array or in cells, I haven't decided yet but probably cells to save memory. (I have 24GB of memory, should I go for variables in order to have faster speed?)

The JSON as of now is <7MB. I don't know how big the parsed object would be (Using the VBA-JSON class). Each row of the data is leaded by a non-continuous ID#. Currently have 20K-30K rows.

Anyway, I have a few other sheets that would want a portion of the parsed data. They would be identified by ID. I know there's autofilter but I wonder if there's other faster options. Maybe get the row number by ID (MATCH?) and pull the other columns on that row?

As said other parts of the code can change like storing the parsed data in arrays or cells.

Comment: If your data is sorted by ID you could conceivably receive some fast result pages from two matches (first and last in block) but the [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is also very quick at determining subsets. Turn off screen updating and enable events for the best results.

Comment: The original data is sorted but it doesn't help. The subsets ID are almost random picks. It's like stock monitoring. Instead of picking a few stocks symbol, I have a thousand ID I want to match with the data.

Comment: You will want to cycle through the ID column, picking up a unique list into a dictionary collection. The dictionary is subsequently used to filter and copy each filtered set to a new worksheet.

Comment: There's an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766306/how-to-cycle-through-a-filtered-range-using-another-auto-filter-on-a-different-c/30767287#30767287).