# vba- split dictionary values

Tags: vba, excel

I joined arrays on a dictionary using this, based on an answer i got in a previous question i asked in this site.

```
ks = Join(Array(data(k, 1), Split(data(k, 3) & "-> ", "-> ")(1)), ChrW(8203))
```

for starters what does the `ChrW(8203)` represent?

[this is how the data i am trying to split looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANEZ5.png)

```
  For c = 1 to Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
      For i = 1 to dic.Count
          If Range("A" & c +1).Value = dic(i) Then
             Range("D") & c + 1).Text = kss(i)    ' << ?
          End If
      Next i
  Next c
```

and i dont know what the **"?"** represents how can i split the two values later? using the `split` function? Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973698/4996248

Comment: If `dic` and `kss` are "Scripting.Dictionary", there is better use than looping dic(i) & kss(i). But please show code for adding keys and values for them. Anyway you should Exit For when there is a match right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution but need to paste image.

Decimal 8203 = Hexadecimal 200B `Hex(8203)`, you can see description from Office apps' Insert Symbol (very useful sometimes), it says **Zero Width Space**:

[image: Symbols]

You can still use it to Split strings with it `Split(StringVariable,ChrW(8203))`. e.g.:
[image: example]