# Unexpected whitespace element inserted in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting

I have a page with a bunch of images, each with auto-generated hyperlinks to their own personal image page; when you click an image, it takes you to a page to view the image on its own. The issue I have is that, when generating the image-viewing page, my uppermost body element doesn't touch the top of the screen because there is unexpected white space, which is detectable in the inspect-element screen.

[image]

I have reformatted the page multiple times but the white space still remains. I am unsure whether this is an issue with the fact that I am rendering the pages using python/flask and passing in the variables as such.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    ​
        <title>Image {{imageNumber}}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/styleSheet.css') }}">
    ​
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1 class="titleText">Thermal Imaging</h1>
        <a href="/static/images/{{imageNumber}}.jpg" download>
            <img class="bigImg" src="/static/images/{{imageNumber}}.jpg">
        </a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I expect the white space that appears to not be there. No error messages appear, but in the inspector I can see (and temporarily delete) the white space causing the issue: it is labelled as  &#8203

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have built-in stylesheets that apply a default margin and/or padding to the `body`. Additionally, an `h1` element has built-in margins as well. You adjust/remove these with CSS rules.

Here's an example that removes the top margin from the `body` and the first `h1` element, allowing the first item in the `body` to be placed at the extreme top of the page:

```css
body, .noTopMargin { margin-top:0; }
```

```html
<h1 class="noTopMargin">I have no top margin</h1>
<h1>I have a top margin</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, though this doesn't work for me. I should have linked my CSS, but I basically already have a bunch of formatting settings (for example, margin-top: 0) however this does not fix the issue. The unexpected element is still being inserted above my <h1>  regardless of changing formatting.

Comment: @LoganCavanah You say that the white space is detectable through inspection in the dev. tools. What do the dev. tools show as being there? Can you update your question with a screen shot of that inspection?

Comment: @LoganCavanah Ok, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973698/whats-html-character-code-8203) may be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was, for me, as follows: I fiddled around with the HTML, reformatting it and deleting blank spaces. I must have, at some point, deleted the zero-width-space character and now it works as intended. I recommend, if you have a similar issue, trying to delete, copy, paste, reformat etc your html until it works.