# Make default double click behavior treat zero width spaces as word characters

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page where some words are split by `&#8203;` so they look e.g. like `​​F​Rig​V​M​External​Variable` but in the code they are actually `F&#8203;Rig&#8203;V&#8203;M&#8203;External&#8203;Variable&#8203;`. And the problem is that when I click the word it selects only a part that is bordered by `&#8203;` while the desirable behavior is for it to select the whole word

How to override default double click behavior in JS so it would treat `&#8203;` not as a word boundary?

Answer (score 1):

You can triple-click to select the entire line/paragraph. Otherwise, `&#8203;` is a word separator as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973698/whats-html-character-code-8203) question, so the default browser action on double click is to select the word under the cursor.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt-br'>
<head>
<title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
a&#8203;better&#8203;test with spaces<br>
a&#8203;better&#8203;test with spaces<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but it doesn't answer the question of how to override default double click behavior so it would treat `&#8203;` not as a word boundary. Mb the question wasn't stated clearly enough. I'll update it

Comment: Javascript. You can use the `event.detail` property of a `click` event handler to capture double-clicks in this handler. Then you can fiddle with answers like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2838358/152016 but I've failed to create a version that can work with text nodes instead of document ones (meaning you would have to enclose each "word" you would like to join with a tag, and then extend the range with `Range.selectNodeContents`).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which preserves the ability for a word to be soft-broken at specific positions but doesn't interfere with selection. It's tag `</wbr>`. When I replace `&#8203;` on `</wbr>` the word can be soft broken at the `</wbr>`s but when I click any part of a word the whole word gets selected.

```html
F<wbr/>Rig<wbr/>V<wbr/>M<wbr/>External<wbr/>Variable<wbr/>
```

Comment: Amazing! Well done man!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need zero width spaces, you should just remove them using `.replace()` and the regex flag `\u` which enables Regex methods to recognize Unicode. The Unicode for a zero width space is: `U+200B` which in the land of JavaScript is: `\u200B`.

```js
function noZero(string) {
  return string.replace(/\u200B/gu, '');
}

const str = document.querySelector(".zero").innerHTML;

const result = noZero(str);

document.querySelector(".clean").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", result);
```

```html
<p class="zero">Try <u>s​e​l​e​c​t​i​n​g</u> the underlined word.</p>

<p class="clean"></p>
```

Comment: But I do need them